# Should I store SKTextures in class or initializers?

Tags: sprite-kit

So I was just wondering which code example is going to use the least amount of ram considering the entire time a scene is open.

```
class Scene: SKScene {
var t1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Happy")
var sprite = SKSpriteNode()

  func loadS()
  {
    sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: t1)
    //SEt position scale and add to parent
  }
}
```

vs

```
class Scene: SKScene {
var sprite = SKSpriteNode()

  func loadS()
  {
    sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "happy"))
    //SEt position scale and add to parent
  }
}
```

I am having performance issues so I am just trying to get every little bit of performance humanly possible!

Also is it possible to use profiler to see how long it takes a function or block of code to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep sprites in memory throughout the app (which will increase performance at the absolutely negligible cost of memory), then just initialize the texture only when you need it to create a sprite(option 2). If, on the other hand, you need to initialize a large amount of sprite nodes that all use the same texture, then yes, it might be worth it to keep the texture as a global variable. Otherwise, there's no need since sprites have their own texture property that retains an SKTexture.

Before you start worrying about performance make sure you are first of all on release mode instead of debug and you are not on the simulator. ***Please*** don't take the simulator's performance at face value. If you use an actual device you will the CPU usage level drop!

Now, if you're still worried by now, then you must have a lot of textures and a ton of physics. You can in fact use the profiler to see how long a code segment takes to run. Look at the Time Profiler Instrument : [official documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/TimeProfilerInstrument/TimeProfilerInstrument.html)

You will be able to see how long a process runs and using call stack information that it gives you can piece together how long certain code runs. From there you can do optimization as you wish. Good luck.

Comment: Just an FYI, but texture data is not "absolutely negligible", in actual practice size of the uncompressed textures in memory is actually the biggest thing that consumes memory in a SpriteKit based game. A developer needs to be really careful to keep memory use low and texture size is the main thing that can use too much memory. Simply loading everything at start time is not a solution except in the most trivial games.